# Angular 13 Not Seeing Custom Pipes

Tags: javascript, angular

i am porting over and angular 6 app to angular 13 and i am having trouble with pipes.  the app wont compile.

i have a custom pipe on a component that the compiler says doesnt exist
Property 'shortDate' does not exist on type 'TransactionsComponent'.

code is as follows (and works in old version of angular)

**angular pipe:**

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
    
    @Pipe({
        name: 'shortDate' 
    })
    export class DateFormatPipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
        override transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
            ///MMM/dd/yyyy 
            return super.transform(value, "MM/dd/yyyy");
        }
    }
```

**html**

```
<div class="dt">{{transaction.transactionDate | date: shortDate}}</div>
```

**Shared Module**

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [  
    DateFormatPipe 
  ],
  imports: [ 
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,  
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpInterceptorModule,  
    ReactiveFormsModule, 
   
  ],
  exports: [ 
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,  
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpInterceptorModule,  
    ReactiveFormsModule ,
   
  ],   
})
export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<SharedModule> {
      return {
        ngModule: SharedModule,
        providers: 
        [   
            DateFormatPipe,  
        ]
      };
    }
  }
```

**consuming module**

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [ 
      ],
      imports: [ 
       SharedModule  
      ],
      providers: [  
      ], 
    })
export class TransactionModule{ }
```

**in app.module**

```
     imports: [ 
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    TransactionModule
  ] ,
```

please note: I have also tried to put the pipe in the exports section of shared module.  that doesnt work either.  i'm sure im just missing something silly. does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try using it like this `<div class="dt">{{transaction.transactionDate | shortDate}}</div>`, worked for me, also I did include it in exports in Shared Module.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="dt">{{transaction.transactionDate | shortDate}}</div>
```

Try adding `standalone: true` flag to the Pipe decorator

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'shortDate',
  standalone: true
})
```

Comment: thank you for the response . i get this error when i tried that.
No pipe found with name 'shortDate'

Comment: i have already tried standalone:true..

. when i do that i am forced to remove it from the declarations in SharedModule.  i moved it to imports.  i still get the same error on the component that the property doesnt exist

Comment: looks like a combination of this standalone: true  and just | shortDate did the trick.  thank you!